# How to parameterize http methods in Jmeter using CSV data config?

Tags: apache, jmeter, parameterized

How to parameterize *http methods in Jmeter* using **CSV data config**?

What I did:
`created an HTTP Request Sampler (method POST)`, but I need to create http request sampler from a csv file including method also.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the HTTP method using Beanshell Preprocessor.

Add a Beanshell preprocessor for your existing HTTP request. Your default HTTP method is POST.

Now lets change it to GET whenever the csv variable 'method' is 'GET'

```
if(vars.get("method").equalsIngoreCase("GET")){
    sampler.setMethod("GET");  //this will change current sampler's http method from POST to GET. 
}
```