# How to Parameterize JMeter HTTP Sampler Method?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, parameterization

can we parameterize the HTTP Sampler method in Jmeter ?
I am using Jmeter 2.13.

I tried the solution remomended here but no luck.

[How to parameterize http methods in Jmeter using CSV data config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729223/how-to-parameterize-http-methods-in-jmeter-using-csv-data-config)

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Hari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a file, i.e. `test.csv` with the following contents:

   ```
   GET
   POST
   ```

   2. Add [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and configure it like:

      - Filename: `test.csv`
      - Variable Names: `METHOD`

        [image: JMeter CSV Data Set]
   3. Add [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and set "Method" to `${METHOD}`

      [image: JMeter HTTP REquest method parameterization]
   4. That's it, when you run your test each iteration it will use the next line from the `test.csv` file

      [image: JMeter parameterize method demo]

---

Also be aware that according to [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) you should always be using the most recent JMeter version so consider upgrading to [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) (or whatever version is available at [JMeter downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) as soon as possible

Comment: This Perfactly Worked. Thanks :)